# JACK Audio not playing

Tags: audio, arch-linux, jackd

I switched to [JACK](http://jackaudio.org/) yesterday on my Arch computer to just play around with it and figure out its uses, but I came across something pretty peculiar with JACK.

It simply won't play audio through my headphones. At first, I tried changing my output device in the jackd, since I thought that I was just on the wrong output device. I had tried each "soundcard" on my computer, but none of them played audio through my headphones. My microphone works fine, though. JACK recognizes the programs playing the audio, as I have checked with an audio visualizer. But my headphones are out of the loop.

From what I can tell, the problem has something to do with JACK not recognizing my headphones as an output device. I thought this had something to do with the fact that my headphones had to be connected through a 3.5 mm headphone jack, but it could be something completely different.

Any solutions to this problem, or is JACK just a lost cause?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Edited it. I hope it provides more detail.